# How to manually calculate dAIC (survey design-based AIC) in R survey package

Tags: r, self-study, generalized-linear-model, survey, aic

In preparation for fitting some more complicated distributions to survey-weighted data, I am trying to reproduce the $d\text{AIC}$ by hand for a simpler distribution (binomial in this case). I am having trouble, and would like some pointers and corrections to my understanding.

The [survey design based AIC](https://academic.oup.com/jssam/article-abstract/3/1/1/915356?redirectedFrom=fulltext) $d\text{AIC}$ is defined by Lumley and Scott in their 2015 paper "AIC and BIC for modeling with complex survey data". The equation is

$$
d\text{AIC} = -2n\hat l(\hat{  \mathbf{\theta}} ) + 2p\hat{\bar{\delta}}
$$

where

- $n$ is the sample size
- $ \hat l(\hat{\theta} )$ is the weighted log-likelihood (Equation 2 of their paper) evaluated at the estimated parameters $\hat{\theta}$
- $p$ is the number of parameters being estimated, i.e. length of $\theta$ vector
- $\hat{\bar{\delta}}$ is the average estimated design effect

In R, I have fitted a binomial GLM in the survey package.

```r
library(survey)
data(api)

dstrat <- svydesign(id= ~ 1,strata= ~ stype, weights= ~ pw, 
                    data=apistrat, fpc= ~ fpc)
mdl <- svyglm(sch.wide ~ ell + meals + mobility, design=dstrat,
              family=quasibinomial())
AIC(mdl)
logLik(mdl)
```

The `logLik` command gives `In logLik.svyglm(mdl) : svyglm not fitted by maximum likelihood.` I am not sure if this is problem - I thought AIC relies on maximum likelihood estimation.

Then, I calculate Equation 2 of the paper, which is the weighted log-likelihood of a binomial GLM with a logit link, by hand.

```r
alogit <- function(x) exp(x) / (1 + exp(x)) 
          # define inverse of the logit function

eta <- predict(mdl, type = "link"); attributes(eta) <- NULL
y <- as.integer(apistrat$sch.wide == "Yes")
lhat <- 1/sum(weights(dstrat)) * sum( 
  weights(dstrat) * log( alogit(eta)^y * (1 - alogit(eta))^(1-y) ) 
)
logLik(mdl) / nrow(apistrat)
lhat # equal
```

I can reproduce the `logLik` of the model by hand, with `lhat`.

Now I need to calculate the design effect $\hat{\bar{\delta}}$. In the paper, on page 5, it says *We can estimate $\hat{\bar{\delta}}$ by $\hat{\bar{\delta}}=\text{tr}\{ n\hat J(\hat\theta)^{-1}\hat V_U(\hat\theta) \} = n\hat J(\hat\theta)\hat V (\hat\theta)$. Both $\hat J$ and $\hat V$ are computed routinely in the course of calculating $\hat\theta$*. I am not sure where to obtain these objects from, presumably they're stored in the `mdl` object somewhere. Also, I am wondering if the last term on that equation is missing the $\text{tr}(\cdot)$ term as $J$ and $V$ are matrices.